# Return different HTTP status codes from Application Service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate Framework and I've created a custom app service that inherits from AsyncCrudAppServiceBase and I've overridden the `Get` function.

```
public override async Task<ExampleDto> Get(EntityDto<int> input)
{
    var example = await Repository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.Id);

    return ObjectMapper.Map<ExampleDto>(example);
}
```

However, because I'm using `FirstOrDefault` if the record doesn't exist it returns `null` and the HTTP Status is 200 instead of 404, which I want.

If I change the LINQ function to `First` or, ideally, `Single` then and exception is thrown but the HTTP Status is 500.

I can check if the record exists but how do I return a different HTTP status from an Application Service?

Comment: Which technology are you using? ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core ? Also which version number? If you are using ASP.NET Core >= 2.1 then the suggested way is, to use Task<IActionResult<T>> as return value of your Controller Methods. This way you can check if "example" is null and return "NotFound()" in this case. Otherwise just return the result of your Mapping. For additional information see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types

Comment: I'm using a framework called ASPNETBoilerplate which has a separation between the API controllers and the application services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using repository get method in your app service.

See 
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#base-repository-methods

Reason being `Repository.Get()` will throw `EntityNotFoundException` when `FirstOrDefault` return null.

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6bce9a0572170e8daf1b21ee982a869714579e2d/src/Abp/Domain/Repositories/AbpRepositoryBase.cs#L73-L82

And when Abp wraps the response, EntityNotFoundException will have NotFound as the HttpStatusCode

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/15e5f33885442bfd0996936191fd964144a95652/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/ExceptionHandling/AbpExceptionFilter.cs#L99-L102